# the model field's form disappears in django admin

Tags: python, django

I have two models, which are User and Record. Each has several fields.

```
from django.db import models

class User(models.Model):
        openid = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        nickname = models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True)
        def __str__(self):
                return self.nickname

class Record(models.Model):
        expression = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        user = models.ForeignKey(User)
        time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        def __str__(self):
                return self.expression
```

I register them in admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import User,Record

class RecordAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        list_display = ('expression','user','time')

class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        empty_value_display = "空"
        list_display = ('openid','nickname')

admin.site.register(User,UserAdmin)
admin.site.register(Record,RecordAdmin)
```

it works well in django admin initially. but one day, the fields of the Record model disppeared. It looks like

[image].

No field displays. It makes me unable to modify or add the values of the Record model. The other model User works well and all data exists in database. So why?

Comment: You're model file is well migrated ? You didn't create the Record class after your last migration ?

Comment: sure, it has migrated. i created the two models at same time. the django version is 1.11.3

Comment: Try to add in your ForeignKey field : `on_delete=models.CASCADE`. It works with your script and `on_delete=models.CASCADE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just have to add `on_delete=models.CASCADE` in your `ForeignKey Field`. When you are using this kind of field, you have to specify the comportment when you make an update, a delete or anything else on this field.

So your script should be like this :

```
class Record(models.Model):
        expression = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        def __str__(self):
                return self.expression
```

This is the result :

[image]

[image]

[image]

### Edit :

You can also modify `null=True` by `default=null`

```
class User(models.Model):
        openid = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        nickname = models.CharField(max_length=20,default=null)
        def __str__(self):
                return self.nickname
```

Comment: I have tried your answer, but Nothing happens. So the records before can not be displayed？

Comment: After the modification, have you migrate your models file ? You have to do that. Then, do you have any traceback ?
It shoud work because my example works on my localhost session

Comment: I have found where the problem is. It is caused by the nickname in User model. The 'null = True' make some user with a null nickname,  while the '\_\_str\_\_' must return a str type. This leads to a type error.  after I replaced it with default='null', it works well. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer according to default value. But, `on_delete=models.CASCADE` should be present too and it missed initialy in your script. So maybe you could accept my answer.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) on_delete was not yet required in django version 1.11.3 that the OP uses. Omitting it should not be a problem for him, other than getting a deprecation warning.